# Boiler Plate Code in WAS ND on Bluemix

Tags: websphere, ibm-cloud, ibm-was-oc

I am trying the WAS ND as a service on Bluemix - And I am trying to deploy a Java DB Web starter boiler plate code- I am able to create datasource and test the connection and I installed the app- But the app is not getting started with the following error :

> Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException:
>   Failed to load webapp: JVMCFRE003 bad major version;
>   class=example/jpa/HelloResource, offset=6 [5/6/16 13:01:51:278 UTC]
>   00000086 SystemErr     R      at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:177)
>   [5/6/16 13:01:51:281 UTC] 00000086 SystemErr     R      at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:901)
>   [5/6/16 13:01:51:281 UTC] 00000086 SystemErr     R      ... 99 more
>   [5/6/16 13:01:51:281 UTC] 00000086 SystemErr     R Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version;
>   class=example/jpa/HelloResource, offset=6

As I understand this error happens when The app is compiled in one version and runs in different version.Though I have compiled the application in Java 1.7 and also validated that version in WAS ND vm is pointing to java 1.7

Any clues on how to fix this ? Or where Should I be validating in the WAS ND on Bluemix.

Comment: What does javap report when run on HelloResource?

Comment: Access the `SystemOut.log` from your WAS in Bluemix and check which Java version it is using. You can do it either via admin console or through file system.

Comment: Can you also provide the exact Java version you complied the application? 
`java -version`
Did you use the IBM JDK or the Oracle JDK?